# Issue with chrome and iPad with querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome

I have the following code:

```
var showonlyswitch = document.querySelectorAll('#showonlyswitch > optgroup > option');
for (var y = 0; y<showonlyswitch.length; y++) {
     showonlyswitch[y].addEventListener('click', showonlyproducts);
}
```

working in firefox, but not in chrome and not in iOS safari.

As far as I know (and "caniuse" tells me), querySelectorAll and addEventListener should both be supported by both browsers. (iOS safari v.8.1 and chrome v.39.0.2171.95 (64-bit))

The function I am calling with this is quite simple:

```
function showonlyproducts() {

    var searchvalue = document.getElementById('showonlyswitch').value;
    if (searchvalue == 1) {
        window.location.href = 'pricing?close=1';
    }
}
```

First I thought `window.location.href` would cause some problems, but I tried to `console.log` some gibberish and it worked in firefox but not in chrome.

I also tried to change

```
var showonlyswitch = document.querySelectorAll('#showonlyswitch > optgroup > option');
```

to

```
var showonlyswitch = document.querySelectorAll('#showonlyswitch > option');
```

but that (obviously) doesn't work in any browser.

The select is separated in some optgroups and the function should trigger on click on an option, as the change event isn't sufficient for the situation because it is possible that a solution is chosen without the change event being triggered (no change).

As I said, the code is working perfectly fine in firefox, so there shouldn't be any typos or something (usually ...), there are no errors in chrome's console.

Are there any known issues which come to your mind with anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding click events to `option` elements is not reliable. Instead use `onchange` event:

```
var showonlyswitch = document.querySelector('#showonlyswitch');
showonlyswitch.addEventListener('change', showonlyproducts);
```

As for this part

> the change event isn't sufficient for the situation because it is possible that a solution is chosen without the change event being triggered

Try tom bind click event on `#showonlyswitch` select element itself rather then `option` elements.